# How can I break away from an SSH session that has crashed?

Tags: ssh, terminal

Many times I have an SSH session that doesn't respond anymore (for example, when I lose internet connection and then reconnect). <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> and a zillion of key presses don't have any effect.

Most of the time I already have `tmux` or `byobu` running already, so I can just start another terminal and reconnect. However it does feel cumbersome. How can I disconnect SSH from the current terminal?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Use the "escape character" (normally, the tilde `~`) to control an SSH session:

- `~` followed by `.` closes the SSH connection;
- `~` followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> suspends the SSH process;
- `~` followed by another `~` sends a literal `~`.

You can set the escape character using the `-e` option to 
[ssh](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/en/man1/ssh.1.html).

Additionally, remember that

> You should also remember to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> before <kbd>~</kbd>. The escape character works when it is the first character in the line. And also you can use <kbd>~</kbd> and later <kbd>?</kbd> to get help from the ssh client. (Thanks to the comment by [Lukasz Stelmach](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/3524/lukasz-stelmach).)

Comment: You should also remember to press `Enter` before `~`. The escape character works when it is first character in the line. And also you can use `~` and later `?` to get help from ssh client.

Comment: `~` followed by `?` gives you a complete list of the supported escape sequences

Answer (score 2):

Openssh can be configured to send client or server alive messages to the other side. If no response is obtained, the connection will be terminated. From the server side, see the `ClientAliveInterval` and `ClientAliveCountMax` config options. From the client side, see the `ServerAliveInterval` and `ServerAliveCountMax` options. `TCPKeepAlive` is also an option, but is spoofable while the former options aren't, so they are probably better.

If you set these to reasonable values, you'll probably never have a connection hang again. The only downside is that your ssh connections might stay open if you would rather they would terminate, for security reasons.

See the [OpenSSH sshd config man page](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=sshd_config) and the [OpenSSH ssh config man page](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ssh_config) for further infrormation.

Answer (score -4):

Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd>