# How do I background an SSH session?

Tags: ssh, escape-characters

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I break away from an SSH session that has crashed?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13996/how-can-i-break-away-from-an-ssh-session-that-has-crashed)

I have started an SSH session on the command line, but now I want to get back to my local command line. For any other process, I would hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, then run `bg`. However, the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> get's sent to the remote, rather than the local SSH process. How do I send it to the local SSH process?

Comment: I've found the answer elsewhere, but not until I'd searched for a while.

Answer (score 26):

There is escape char in ssh, by default this is tilde `~`. It is recognized only after <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

To suspend your ssh session type <kbd>~</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>.

Refer to the `ssh(1)` manual under **ESCAPE CHARACTERS** for more information.

Comment: note: ^Z escape not available to multiplexed sessions (connect via `controlpath` option)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe of less value nowadays, but in my **$HOME/.bashrc** I aliased ssh to

```
alias ssh='ssh -e ^]'
```

That way I avoid potential conflict with ordinary **~** usage albeit fresh after a newline.
Instead, to escape out of an ssh session, I press <kbd>Ctrl ]</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl Z</kbd>, which coincides with the way we used to do it under old telnet, long ago (or still on some embedded Linux devices, TVs etc. that don't have sshd).