# Can I bridge "backwards" from an ssh connection to my local emacs-server?

Tags: ssh, editors, emacs

I'd very much like to log in to a remote machine with `ssh` and via the `$EDITOR` environment variable (or something similar) be able to edit in my local Emacs. In this case, specifically for when I log in and run `psql` and use the `\e` `psql` command to edit queries. Being able to edit them in my local Emacs would be a huge bonus in my work flow.

I have a nagging suspicion that there is no way this can be done, but before giving up I thought I'd throw it out here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually do this using [tramp](http://savannah.gnu.org/projects/tramp):

> TRAMP stands for `Transparent Remote (file) Access, Multiple Protocol'. This package provides remote file editing, similar to Ange-FTP. The difference is that Ange-FTP uses FTP to transfer files between the local and the remote host, whereas TRAMP uses a combination of rsh and rcp or other work-alike programs, such as ssh/scp.

Add these lines to your `~/.emacs` file ([source](http://jeremy.zawodny.com/blog/archives/000983.html)):

```
(require 'tramp)
(setq tramp-default-method "scp")
```

You should then be able to open the remote file like this:

```
emacs /remote.server.com:/remote/path/foo.txt
```

---

Specifically for use with the `psql` command you would need something different though. Don't have a way of testing this now but perhaps setting emacs as an alias to your local emacs *might* work. Add this line to your remote `.bashrc` file:

```
alias emacs='ssh user@local emacs'
```

Comment: This is true stuff, but I don't think it accomplishes quite what this guy is looking for. How would this get instantiated from the remote shell?

Comment: @Caleb well, ah, point, not sure how to configure this for use with `\e psql`. See updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiarized with `emacs` or `psql`. But...

Looks like you can use `sshfs` to mount your remote server and execute everything locally:

```
sshfs user@host mount/directory/
cd mount/directory && emacs
```

If you need run commands in the remote machine, you can mount with `sshfs`, then access with `ssh` then [use ssh escape characters to suspend the ssh session](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42365/how-do-i-background-an-ssh-session) and run emacs in your machine (editing the remote files mounted with `sshfs`).

**Another solution** would be install `emacs` in the remote machine and copy your configuration (I chose this solution aggregated in a git repo for my vim stuff)

Answer (score -1):

This can't be done as you have described it. You could use SFTP (possibly through FUSE) to edit files on the remote system. It might be possible to do something really creative with scripts and piping, but it's not built-in functionality.