# Setting `$EDITOR` to open file in local emacs session

Tags: emacs, remote

Sometimes I need to issue a remote command which uses `$EDITOR` to pick the, well, editor (think `git commit` for example). Is it possible to use the local emacs session to open it via, for example, port forwarding (I have tramp installed)?

Comment: Does [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74867/can-i-bridge-backwards-from-an-ssh-connection-to-my-local-emacs-server) do what you want?

Comment: Another approach: http://andy.wordpress.com/2013/01/03/automatic-emacsclient/

Comment: @devnull due to presence of NAT closer to pbm solution but essentially yes. I voted to close (the linked question could be titled better I guess - it did not come up in search).