# Detach from tmux session and close ssh session with 1 command

Tags: ssh, tmux

Frequently I want to exit my ssh session without also killing the tmux session I am using. To do this I have to run the following commands:

```
tmux detach
exit
```

or alternatively use the shortcut `Ctrl+B D` and then `exit`.

Is there a way to streamline this into one command? I've tried using an alias but it seems to execute both commands inside the tmux session.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `tmux detach -P`.

Or use <kbd>~</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> to exit ssh (which will detach tmux because its tty disappears).

Comment: `tmux detach -P` did the trick for me thanks!

Comment: I still ending up in the hosts bash session

Comment: this works but it also closes the ssh session to the machine on which tmux was running.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of automating the deconnection, I would change the connection. I’m guessing you currently connect using SSH, then run `tmux attach`; if you combine both steps,

```
 ssh -t user@host tmux attach
```

the SSH session becomes tied to the lifetime of the attaching `tmux` process, rather than the initial shell, and detaching from `tmux` will automatically close the SSH connection.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it doesn't help me because of my particularly weird setup, but I'm sure it will help others.

Comment: Hopefully someone else will come up with an approach which will also work for you!

Answer (score 2):

Unless your setup is *too* weird, you can [kill the SSH connection](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/13998/70524) with <kbd>Enter</kbd> <kbd>~</kbd> <kbd>.</kbd> (all separate keypresses). The `tmux` session should become detached (like with any other SSH disconnection).

Comment: Yea, I've seen this one but I like to enter commands at the command line rather than using escape sequences :>

Answer (score 1):

[*Automatically start tmux on ssh connection. Logout on detach.*](http://blog.thelinuxkid.com/2013/06/automatically-start-tmux-on-ssh.html)
by [thelinuxkid](https://www.blogger.com/profile/12414011760956398509) does exactly what OP asks, entirely within bash:

> This bit automatically opens tmux when ssh'ing into a server. 
> If a session does not exist a new one is created. 
> Otherwise, the last session is attached. 
> This should always be run last either in .bashrc or as a script in .bashrc.d. 
> The user is logged out from the server on detach.
>
> ```
> # This should always be run last either in .bashrc or as a script in .bashrc.d
> if [[ -z "$TMUX" ]]; then
>     tmux has-session &> /dev/null
>     if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
>       exec tmux new
>       exit
>     else
>       exec tmux attach
>       exit
>     fi
> fi
> ```